# creating adjacency list in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, adjacency-list, adjacency-matrix

I am new to Pig. Could somebody point me how this can be done ?
I have a text file containing adjacency matrix:

```
*   x1  x2  x3  x4  x5
x1  0   1   0   1   1
x2  0   0   0   1   0
x3  0   0   0   0   1
x4  0   0   0   0   0
x5  0   1   0   0   0
```

I want to create adjacency list from this matrix which should look like this

```
x1  x2
x1  x4
x1  x5
x2  x4
x3  x5
x5  x2
```

so After I read matrix from the file : A = LOAD 'matrix.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS(x, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5); so DUMP A is now

```
(*,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) 
(x1,0,1,0,1,1) 
(x2,0,0,0,1,0)
(x3,0,0,0,0,1)
(x4,0,0,0,0,0)
(x5,0,1,0,0,0)
```

Now I want to create group that maps each x1, x2,x3,x4,x5 of the first column to other columns that have at least one 1

Any help appreciated !